# reshaping a tensor with padding in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

How do I reshape a tensor with dimensions `(30, 35, 49)` to `(30, 35, 512)` by padding it?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

While @nemo's solution works fine, there is a pytorch internal routine, [`torch.nn.functional.pad`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#torch.nn.functional.pad), that does the same - and which has a couple of properties that a `torch.ones(*sizes)*pad_value` solution does not (namely other forms of padding, like reflection padding or replicate padding ... it also checks some gradient-related properties):

```py
import torch.nn.functional as F
source = torch.rand((5,10))
# now we expand to size (7, 11) by appending a row of 0s at pos 0 and pos 6, 
# and a column of 0s at pos 10
result = F.pad(input=source, pad=(0, 1, 1, 1), mode='constant', value=0)
```

The semantics of the arguments are:

- `input`: the source tensor,
- `pad`: a list of length `2 * len(source.shape)` of the form (begin last axis, end last axis, begin 2nd to last axis, end 2nd to last axis, begin 3rd to last axis, etc.) that states how many dimensions should be added to the beginning and end of each axis,
- `mode`: `'constant'`, `'reflect'` or `'replicate'`. Default: `'constant'` for the different kinds of padding
- `value` for constant padding.

Comment: Actually, the order of dimensions is reversed. So the first two values in the pad input correspond to the last dimension (see https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.functional.pad)

Comment: Does padding a tensor affect the value of the gradient? If yes, how so?

Comment: Yes, padding can affect the value of the gradient. How depends on the operation. My recommendation is to write out the function you are padding the input to, and do some steps of the math to see how the output of the function depends on the padded values.

Answer (score 44):

The simplest solution is to allocate a tensor with your padding value and the target dimensions and assign the portion for which you have data:

```
target = torch.zeros(30, 35, 512)
source = torch.ones(30, 35, 49)
target[:, :, :49] = source
```

Note that there is no guarantee that padding your tensor with zeros and then multiplying it with another tensor makes sense in the end, that is up to you.

Comment: the first 2 dimensions are still identical which doesn't happen in most cases

Comment: In my experiments, this will break the computation graph: a = torch.zeros((2,10), requires_grad=True)
b = torch.randn(10, requires_grad=True)
a[0] = b
loss = a.sum()
loss.backward()
RuntimeError: leaf variable has been moved into the graph interior

Answer (score 13):

A module that might be clearer and more suitable for this question is `torch.nn.ConstantPad1d` e.g.

```py
import torch
from torch import nn

x = torch.ones(30, 35, 49)
padded = nn.ConstantPad1d((0, 512 - 49), 0)(x)
```

Answer (score 8):

[image]

> ```
> import torch.nn.functional as F
> data = torch.ones(4, 4)
> # pad(left, right, top, bottom)
> new_data = F.pad(input=data, pad=(1, 1, 1, 1), mode='constant', value=0)
> print(new_data)
> ```

Comment: thanks for this, if I padd in the middle of training, does this retain the grad of the original tensor?

Answer (score 2):

The idea here is to use torch.cat to pad across that particular dimension with your desired tensor. The example should make it clearer.

```
In [1]: import torch

In [2]: a = torch.randn(30, 35, 49)

In [3]: b = torch.randn(30, 35, 512)

In [4]: padder = torch.zeros(30,35,512 - 49)

In [5]: padded_a = torch.cat([a,padder], dim = 2) # Choose your desired dim

In [6]: padded_a.shape
Out[6]: torch.Size([30, 35, 512])

In [7]: target = torch.randn(30,35,512)

In [8]: target = torch.cat([target,padded_a], dim = 2)

In [9]: target.shape
Out[9]: torch.Size([30, 35, 1024])
```

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to illustrate the answer given by @ghchoi. Because I had a little trouble following it.

I want to fit an image from standard mnist of size `(N,1,28,28)` into LeNet (proposed way back in 1998) due to kernel size restriction expects the input to be of the shape `(N,1,32,32)`. So suppose we try to mitigate this problem by padding.

#### before padding

before padding a single image, it is of the size `(1,28,28).`
Thus we have three dimensions.

[image: before_padding]

#### after padding

after padding , to create an image of size `(1,32,32)`. Notice the `pad=(2,2,2,2,0,0)`

This is because I added two zeros to the x axis before and after the first `(2,2)` and two zeros after yaxis `(2,2)`, leaving the channel column alone thus `(0,0)`. `value` indicates that the padding would be 0.

[image: after_padding]

Thanks!