# How to change PyTorch tensor into a half size and/or double size with different dimension?

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm new to PyTorch and tensor data thing. I have a problem about switching shape of tensors.

I have two questions.

First, what should I do if I have a tensor with `torch.Size([8, 512, 16, 16])` and I want to change it into `torch.Size([8, 256, 32, 32])` which is double size of the original tensor.

Second, what should I do if I have a tensor with `torch.Size([8, 256, 32, 32])` and I want to change it into `torch.Size([8, 512, 16, 16])` which is half size of the original tensor.

In the first question, I've tried on `ZeroPadding2D(8)` function to reshape it into `torch.Size([8, 512, 32, 32])` but I don't know how to change the 2nd dimension which is 512 into 256.

The actual usage in the first question is something like this.

```py
x = input # torch.Size([8, 512, 16, 16])
x = layer(x) # torch.Size([8, 256, 32, 32]
x = x + input # what I want to do is adding tensor values before and after passing the layer together (like skip connection)
```

I expect the output of adding two tensors to be success but the actual output is an error about unequal size in dimensions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For the first case, use `resize_()` to change second dimension from 512 to 256 and then allocate a tensor with your padding value and the target dimensions and assign the portion for which you have data.

  ```
  import torch

  target_output = torch.zeros(8, 256, 32, 32)

  in_tensor = torch.randn(8, 512, 16, 16)
  out_temp = in_tensor.resize_((8, 256, 16, 16))

  target_output[:, :, :16, :16] = out_temp
  print(target_output.shape)

  # output:
  # torch.Size([8, 256, 32, 32])
  ```

  You can also use `torch.nn.ConstantPad2d()` and then `resize_()` as below:

  ```
  in_tensor = torch.randn(8, 512, 16, 16)
  m = nn.ConstantPad2d((8, 8, 8, 8), 0)
  out_tensor = m(in_tensor).resize_(8, 256, 16, 16)
  print(out_tensor.shape) 

  # output:
  # torch.Size([8, 256, 32, 32])
  ```

  Alternatively, you can also use `torch.nn.ConstantPad2d()` and `copy_()` like below:

  ```
  import torch.nn as nn
  in_tensor = torch.randn(8, 512, 16, 16)  # shape [8, 512, 16, 16]
  m = nn.ConstantPad2d((8, 8, 8, 8), 0) 
  temp = m(in_tensor)                      # shape [8, 512, 32, 32]
  out_tensor = torch.zeros(8, 256, 32, 32) # shape [8, 256, 32, 32]
  out_tensor = out_tensor[:,:,:,:].copy_(temp[:,:256,:,:]) # shape [8, 256, 32, 32]
  ```

  You can read more about reshaping a tensor with padding in pytorch from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48686945/reshaping-a-tensor-with-padding-in-pytorch).
- For the second case, you can simply use `resize_()` for resizing your tensor to half the size.

  ```
  in_tensor = torch.randn(8, 256, 32, 32)
  out_tensor = in_tensor.resize_(8, 512, 16, 16)
  print(out_tensor.shape)

  # output:
  # torch.Size([8, 512, 16, 16])
  ```

  Alternatively, you can use `copy_` as below:

  ```
  in_tensor = torch.randn(8, 256, 32, 32)
  temp_tensor = torch.zeros(8, 512, 16, 16) # shape [8, 512, 16, 16]
  temp_tensor[:,:256,:,:].copy_(in_tensor[:,:,:16,:16]) # shape [8, 512, 16, 16]
  out_tensor = temp_tensor # shape [8, 512, 16, 16]
  ```

  Without using `copy_()`:

  ```
  in_tensor = torch.randn(8, 256, 32, 32)
  out_tensor = torch.zeros(8, 512, 16, 16) # shape [8, 512, 16, 16]
  out_tensor[:,:256,:,:] = in_tensor[:,:,:16,:16]
  ```

Comment: I used resize_() and got `RuntimeError: cannot resize variables that require grad` then I use reshape instead (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50718045/resize-pytorch-tensor) but still got another error `RuntimeError: shape '[8, 256, 16, 16]' is invalid for input of size 1048576`

Comment: then try third way using padding along with copy_()

Comment: @cross_knight, sorry that I haven't consider the situation where you want to resize variable, having require_grad=True. My bad. I added other ways of resizing. Please try those.

Comment: I've tried copy_() and it seems work on the first case. I will try on the second case and will update results. Thank you.

Comment: Conv2d may be an alternative way to change the 2nd tensor dimension

Comment: Yeah, rightly said. Like this I guess: `x = torch.randn(8, 256, 32, 32)
conv_layer = nn.Conv2d(256, 512, 3, stride=2, padding=1)
res = conv_layer(x)`